# Selenium find element and click on it

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get Selenium to click on `View All Companies` button, but i'm not sure what am I doing wrong. It returns `no element found`

**html code**

```
<div class="screener-toggles">
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="button selected" data-name="advanced-screener">Search by Screener<span data-name="advanced-screener" class="arrow selected"></span></span>
    <span class="button" data-name="alpha-factors">Search by Alpha Factors<span data-name="alpha-factors" class="arrow"></span></span>
    <span class="button" data-name="all-companies">View All Companies<span data-name="all-companies" class="arrow"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**python code I wrote**

```
element1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('View All Companies')
element1.click()
# I have tried all-companies instead of View All Companies as well. But still doesn't work
```

Should I not be using `find_elements_by_class_name`?

Any advice on what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View All Companies` is text, not the class. Try looking by text with `css_selector` or `xpath`

```
element1 = find_element_by_css_selector('span:contains("View All Companies")')

element1 = find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "View All Companies")]')
```

Or by the `data-name` attribute which contains `all-companies`

```
element1 = find_element_by_css_selector('span[data-name*="all-companies"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

**try xpath**: `"//span[contains(text(),'View All Companies')]"`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should not use the `find_elements_by_class_name` instead of use `find_element_by_class_name`.

`find_elements_by_class_name` is used when your expecting your locator to return more than 1 element. for a specific element use only `find_element_by_class_name`.

Another thing is I am not able to see any class name as `View All Companies` in your HTML code. Please look into your HTML and select classname or other locator carefully

Hope it will help you

Comment: That was the entire HTML related to the buttons.. Is there another way of clicking the button based on the HTML I posted?

Comment: Yes you can .. can you please comment the exact element/HTML code you are looking for